# How can a Jenkins input step be completed via APIs?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have a Jenkins pipeline defined that includes [an input step](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-input-step/). A human can provide the input by clicking in the Jenkins UI and there is an HTTP endpoint to provide input as well.

Is it possible to provide the input via Groovy API calls?  For instance, could a parallel step in the same pipeline provide the input values? Or, could a completely different build provide input values via Groovy code?

The reason I'd like to use Groovy is to keep the input providing entirely in the Jenkins system and avoid having to provide authentication credentials for the HTTP endpoint.

Comment: you mean without using `input` DSL, you want to create an approval flow with groovy?

Comment: I'd like to have an `input` DSL in the pipeline so that a human can click to progress through the pipeline. I'd also like to have a different pipeline (or a parallel task) that can provide the input in some situations.

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar problem (one pipeline should be able to trigger input steps in other pipelines).

This worked in the Jenkins script console and should work in a pipeline:

```
import org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.support.steps.input.*
  
def build = Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName("TestInputPipeline").getLastBuild()
def action = build.getAction(InputAction.class)
 
action.getExecutions().get(0).proceed([])
```

TestInputPipeline is the name of a test pipeline with a single input.
If your input has parameters, you will probably be able to provide them with the map in the proceed call.

This Input Step Plugin test code helped us: https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-input-step-plugin/blob/master/src/test/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/support/steps/input/InputStepRestartTest.java

JavaDoc can be found here: https://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/pipeline-input-step/index.html